# Oracle 12c CLOB data type is not working as expected

Tags: oracle, clob, oracle12c

```
I have This Oracle 12c Procedure

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOGINCHECK(SQLQRY IN CLOB)
AS
    C INTEGER;
    N INTEGER;
    RC SYS_REFCURSOR;
  stmt clob:= To_Clob('begin ' || sqlqry || '; end;');
BEGIN
    C := SYS.DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    SYS.DBMS_SQL.PARSE(C,stmt ,DBMS_SQL.native);
    N := SYS.DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(C);
    SYS.DBMS_SQL.GET_NEXT_RESULT(C,RC);
    SYS.DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(RC);
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
when OTHERS then
    RAISE;
END LOGINCHECK;
```

I Call This Procedure in Anonymous Block Like This (Download XML Data from here: [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwAVQqYmX0-zQ1d1VnNmZndfcVE/view?usp=sharing))

```
declare stmt clob := 'INWARDPKG.MACHINEINWARD_VALIDATING(XMLDOC => XMLTYPE.CREATEXML(paste xml from link))'; --The parameter value is a xml you can download it from above link
begin
LOGINCHECK(SQLQRY => STMT);
end;
```

But I am getting Error PLS-00172: string literal too long.

If i reduce xml size to 40-50 elements like remove some elements. this works fine.

Comment: Not sure I quite understand how you're assigning/passing the document you linked to. But that is rather more than 32k characters, so you can't assign it to a CLOB as a string literal. Your concatenation inside the procedure will fail too. Where is the document coming from? You may need to read it from somewhere in chunks and append it to the CLOB variable.

Comment: I call logincheck(sqlqry=> parameter) procedure from my .net code and the sqlqry parameter is passed from .net alongwith xml data which is around 5 MB. the begin  procedure_name end; string is created in .net and passed to sqlqry parameter. thus i need not to do add stmt clob:= To_Clob('begin ' || sqlqry || '; end;'); in logincheck(sqlqry=> parameter). also i cannot create chunk of xml.

Comment: I am sending sqlqry parameter as OracleDbType.Clob from .net code but getting same pls-00172 error

Comment: Cross post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/80629/1822

Comment: sir if this is treated as cross post pls let me know which one should i delete stackexchange or stockoverflow post.

Comment: Dear Alex, you told  **Your concatenation inside the procedure will fail too.** but if i send only 40-50 elements in xml then i successfully executes. no error occures.

Answer (score 0):

In your first line `declare stmt clob := 'INWARDPKG.MACHINEINWARD_VALIDATING...` you are defining your CLOB. Since you are using a string literal to define your CLOB, you are facing the limits of string literals (see [Oracle 12c Documenation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218)).

To solve your problem you have to build your CLOB step by step, using the [DBMS_LOB package](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lob.htm#ARPLS600) and appending strings not longer than 4000 bytes until your CLOB is complete.

The basic idea:

```sql
DECLARE
  C CLOB := TO_CLOB('First 4000 bytes');
  V VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  V := 'Next 4000 bytes';
  DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(C, LENGTH(V), V);

  -- more WRITEAPPEND calls until C is complete

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CLOB-Length: ' || DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(C));
END;
```